# Three rings to rule them all

Tags: riddle

Three rings to rule them all,
Nine men fighting against nine.
Closing the lines, capture is done,
I win if seven are mine.

Three men are flying, but more are not.
But on a plane they are all.
Now can you tell from this what I am?
For answers to this I now call.

Comment: assuming this is inspired from tolkien

Comment: Judging from the 2nd line, I think the answer is ROT13(onfronyy), but I'm from the wrong part of the world to know much about this or how the other clues fit.

Comment: Incidentally I proved years ago that the win if captured 7 rule is unnecessary.

Comment: @Joshua: What do you mean with "unnecessary"? Of course you could just play on until all are captured (at which point the rule that you lose if you can't move kicks in), but since as soon as one player has only two stones it is obvious who will win (you can't capture with just two men left), there's no point in playing further.

Comment: @celtschk: The winning sequence by three in a row is at most 4 moves if you have 3 men left. It's longer if you have 4 men left (can't fly) but equally inevitable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't solve it completely, but I think it is

> Nine men's morris (lots of references to the rules of the game: nine pieces on each side, three on the same line means capture, capture seven pieces and you win, when only three pieces are left, "flying" is allowed).

Comment: Could you edit this answer to add in an explanation as to why you think it is correct? Thanks!

Comment: If by *"I can't solve it completely"* you mean the two lines 1) *"Three rings to rule them all"* and 2) *"But on a plane they are all"*: By 1) the three squares on the board are probably meant. And for 2): *"plane"* can also mean *"surface"* or *"area"*.

Comment: That was fast! And @LukasRotter is right on the remaining points.