# Three rings to rule them all (again)

Tags: riddle

Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44031/three-rings-to-rule-them-all)

```
Three rings to rule them all,
Seven a side to battle.
Two distracted by a glint,
Trying to catch the tattle.

All are flying, holding on
But on a plane they're not.
Four balls are needed to play this game.
Can you tell me what?
```

Comment: I guess it's not a riddle if you just describe the game

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> Quidditch

because

Three rings to rule them all,

> Three rings are the goalposts

Seven a side to battle.

> Seven in each team

Two distracted by a glint,

> The seekers

Trying to catch the tattle.

> the golden snitch

All are flying, holding on

> Flying on brooms

But on a plane they're not.
Four balls are needed to play this game.

> Quaffle, the golden snitch, and two bludgers

Can you tell me what?

Comment: Haha, that easy, huh?

Comment: yeah, too easy :/